# Why distance matrix api always returning the status "ZERO_RESULTS"?

Tags: android, google-api, location, distance

I am using the distance matrix api to calculate the distance between one source and multiple destinations. The source latitude / longitude and destination latitudes / longitudes are perfect. Also the route is existing in Google maps between those points. But the api is always returning the status "ZERO_RESULTS". What is the reason for this issue and how it could be solved.

The response from distance matrix api is as follows :

```
"rows" : [

 {

  "elements" : [

  {

    "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"

 },

{

    "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"

},

.

.

.

.

):  }

] } ],  "status" : "OK" }
```

Answer (score 0):

**As per Google Description distance matrix api**

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=**YOUR_API_KEY**

may be there's something wrong implementation in your code
try this way :)

Answer (score 0):

This link is working fine

As per Google Description distance matrix api

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31424156)