# Google Distance Matrix ZERO_RESULTS returned

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, distance

#### Preface

I've been working with the Google Maps API for quite some time, previously being able to successfully use the Distance Matrix service [here](https://github.com/jamez14/TrailFinder/blob/master/app/js/map.js). Then I decided to do some refactoring and issues arose...

#### Current Issue

When trying to get the results of the Distance Matrix service, the `rows` object contains an empty (`status: ZERO_RESULTS`) array of objects.

**The empty object during runtime below:**

[image: the empty object during runtime]

**Normally it would look like this below:**

[image: normal object during runtime]

#### The code

An array of `coords` gets passed into the `distanceMatrixCoords()` function. They look like this:

[image: the coords array]

And the other variables, such as `var origins = pos;` is populated correctly with a coordinates string.

The entire file containing this code is **[available here](https://github.com/jamez14/TrailFinder.Site/blob/master/src/js/modules/map.js)**

```
function distanceMatrixCoords(coords) {
    var origins = pos;
    var destinations = coords;
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

    service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [origins],
            destinations: destinations,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        },
        callback
    );

    function callback(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            var origins = response.originAddresses;
            var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
            var distanceElement = [];
            var theRow = null;

            for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
                
                var results = response.rows[i].elements;

                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                    var element = results[j];
                    var distance = element.distance.text;
                    var duration = element.duration.text;
                    var from = origins[i];
                    var to = destinations[j];

                    distanceElement[j] = document.createElement('p');
                    distanceElement[j].innerHTML = results[j].distance.text;
                    distanceElement[j].className = 'distance-cell';
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Ultimately, based on the code above, the line `var results = response.rows[i].elements;` is where the code breaks. `response.rows` is the object that has the multiple **ZERO_RESULTS** in the array. Compared to my previous code (linked above), the `distanceMatrixCoords()` function receives the exact same type of data as before.

The `response` object that is passed into the `callback()` function contains these values:
[image: response object]

`destinationAddresses` and `originAddresses` are populated correctly with coordinates that look like this comma separated value, `"41.0259285,81.5899887"`. Once again the `rows` array is the issue.

I have looked at many other sources for an answer, but the Distance Matrix service of the Google Maps API does not seem to have many resources available out there. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684460/why-distance-matrix-api-always-returning-the-status-zero-results), but no answers have been recorded yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was my coordinates were being returned incorrectly from the service I built to get data. The coordinates are, for example, `41.0259285,81.5899887` when they should be `41.0259285,-81.5899887`. The minus sign in front of the longitude is missing, therefore the coordinate is not valid and the distance matrix service doesn't know what to do with them.

Comment: some logitudes contains "-" and some not, so its not always necessary to include "-", just put a "," between latitude and longitude for example - 11.519588,79.325157

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but had not specified the "region" (aka country code) and had sent over a 'destination' which was a place in the US, as well as a set of long/lat coords.

Adding the expected country fixed the issue.